# Jquery ajaxStart and blockUI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, blockui

Using Asp.Net MVC 3 (Razor). I'm trying to add the blockUI plug in to show loading indicator when calling actions with @Ajax.ActionLink

It works fine if I use the default call of

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI);
```

But when I try to customize the message using the following, the UI is blocked as soon as the page loads. Can someone advise the correct format?

```
$(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI({ 
     message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' 
}));
```

Comment: Are you calling any Ajax methods automatically when the page loads?

Comment: No, nothing is being called when the page loads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second piece of code, you are actually executing the blockUI method.

Wrap it in an anonymous function:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
     $.blockUI({ 
         message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' 
     });
});
```

---

Working example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/NUASF/)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it give and error "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'blockUI'"

Comment: I've made a quick test in jsfiddle (see the answer for the link - it's a dummy ajax request but it show the blockUI custom message). For your error, it could be you did not correctly included the blockUI file, although it is strange it work with default settings...

Comment: Guys, this one helped (as did the similar answers). The problem with the error was down to Jquery being registered twice in the page, second one was with the Telerik ScriptManager which wasn't obvious

Comment: Makes sense now, as the second include of jquery would erase the previous `jQuery/$` variable where the blockUI plugin was registered. Glad you found a solution to ur problem !

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the blockui stuff in a function:

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (){
    $.blockUI({ 
       message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' 
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it give and error "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'blockUI'"

Answer (score 0):

include the jquery js file and the **blockUI js file**, and **then** execute the code

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function (){
    $.blockUI({ 
       message: '<h1><img src="busy.gif" /> Just a moment...</h1>' 
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, Jquery and Jblock are included. I've tested this by getting the default method $(document).ajaxStart($.blockUI); to work fine

When I try to use the suggested code instead I get the error  "Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'blockUI'" when I dubug